# Compiling Wanderlust for Windows and use it for Gmail

Tags: windows, email, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to get [Wanderlust](http://www.gohome.org/wl/) working in Windows to connect to Gmail.  Compiling the code is much more painful than expected.  Here are the barriers so far:

1. Can't download [dependent packages](http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_4.html#SEC4): SEMI, APEL, and FLIM.  I eventually found newer versions, but I'm not sure they will work.  Anyone have the older versions?
2. Needs make and install.  I used MSYS and it seems to have compiled okay.
3. SSL support.  I was getting a "Cannot open load file: ssl" error.  I found an ssl.el that comes with w3.  So installed w3.
4. Bash command in ssl.el:  ssl-get-command is running something from /bin/sh (not a directory I have in Windows).  I really don't want to refactor this code.  Is there a better way?

[Others](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/06/e-mail-with-wanderlust.html) speak very highly of Wanderlust, so I want to give it a try.  I feel like I'm almost there, but am pretty much worn out with all the crazy configuration I have to do.  Does anyone have this working on Windows?  I'm pretty sure it will work with Gmail, because of [this](http://box.matto.nl/emacsgmail.html) post.  But will it work in Windows too?  If you have a few pointers, please help.

Answer (score 2):

ssl.el is part of wanderlust. Just look in the wanderlust/utils directory.

For STARTTLS you may either use the starttls or gnutls-cli programs.

Unfortunately, both of these programs use signals (SIGALRM to be precise) which are not supported on Windows.

You need to use the Cygwin ports of these programs -- not MSYS!

Additionally, if you're using a Windows port of Emacs (ie. not Cygwin's emacs) you need to modify starttls.el (which is part of GNU Emacs) because the *signal-process* function doesn't do anything regarding SIGALRM. Replace all instances of

```
(signal-process (process-id process) 'SIGALRM)
```

with

```
(call-process kill-program nil nil nil
                  "-ALRM" (format "%d" (process-id process)))
```

and initialize *kill-program* somewhere apropriately to point to cygwin's kill.exe:

```
(setq kill-program "c:/cygwin/bin/kill.exe")
```

If you want to use SSL you have to set `ssl-certificate-verification-policy` to a value greater than 0. Otherwise connecting to Gmail would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed wl on a linux host, and had the same issue with not being able to locate the dependencies as specified. However, I, like you, found the 'more recent versions' and used them. They did indeed work fine, so unless those new versions have added any incompatibility with windows, they shouldn't present any problem.

The error you're receiving is because it's not finding the 'install' utility, which is part of GNU coreutils. Autotools (and it's family) depend on install being able to work, so if you want to continue with the cygwin method, then installing autotools should bring in the install program.

(I have no idea if wl will compile/work using cygwin otherwise, though.)

Comment: I used MSYS and it seemed to go okay.  However, I followed the instructions at http://box.matto.nl/emacsgmail.html to get it to work with GMail.  I keep getting an error of "Cannot open load file: ssl".  Maybe I need to somehow install SSL support on Emacs.  This is getting very tricky.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and updated the question.  I'm still stuck.  Can you get to Gmail on Linux?  Now there's a bounty.

Comment: I think the SSL support you need is the 'starttls' package mentioned here:

http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_6.html

You'll likely need a msys build of openssl installed, I believe one exists (distributed on the msys sourceforge files list), but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 1):

Using the wl configuration here:

http://box.matto.nl/emacsgmail.html

After adding ssl.el from here:

http://quimby.gnus.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/gnus/contrib/ssl.el

I am able to get wanderlust talking just fine to gmail on a linux configuration of wanderlust, and since the ssl.el file there isn't really system-dependent (although it does require the openssl command-line tools), I don't see that there should be any problem with it working on msys.

The 'cannot open load file: ssl' error is exactly what I ran into until I installed that ssl.el file too :)

Edit; Just in case you have trouble finding it, the MSYS port of openssl you'll want is here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS%20openssl/

[posted as a new answer since I think you'll get a notification that way :)]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Now, Emacs just hangs when sending mail.  I see a new openssl process being created, but it just won't send mail.  Does yours work with Gmail (SSL is at smtp.gmail.com:465)?  It works okay when I use openssl directly, but I don't know what Wanderlust is sending see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136599/how-to-create-man-in-the-middle-instrumentation

Comment: BTW: I was able to use IMAP, just not SMTP, so SSL is working but they are different servers with different certs.