# How to create Man in the Middle instrumentation

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, fiddler

I'm trying to see how a [certain application](http://www.gohome.org/wl/) is talking to a server in SSL.  Basically, the process just hangs when it claims to have done some SSL communication.  I want to debug the problem by catching the traffic, but I can't really use a sniffer since SSL will probably look like a hexdump.

Is there a good man-in-the-middle tool that I could use as instrumentation?  I just need something that will show me the decrypted communication.  Hopefully very easy to setup.  I could even point the application to any IP address/port available to my machine (eg localhost:8888), so proxies would be fine.  Also, I can probably configure the application to accept any certificate.

What do you use to simulate a man-in-the-middle (mitm) SSL attack?

UPDATE:  I tried fiddler and can't get it to work.  I installed openssl and typed the following command:
`openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`

Gmail responds with their certificate and a `220 mx.google.com ESMTP ...`.  However, Fiddler does not capture the traffic.  I set the WinINET options in fiddler to "Use the same proxy server for all protocols".  Can anyone else get this to work (or not work)?  I think I need to find a way to have openssl use a proxy.

Comment: Did you configure fiddler to decrypt HTTPS? http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Is the application you are trying to debug connecting over https?

Comment: The application is SMTP encrypted in SSL.

Comment: Fiddler debugs HTTP(S) traffic, and won't be able to display anything useful for SMTP traffic.

Comment: Did you got it working with fiddler?

Comment: I can't remember, but if I were to do the same thing today, I'd use http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: There is also mitmproxy for HTTPS http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/ and sslsplit for arbitrary TLS http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/08/04/use-sslsplit-to-transparently-sniff-tls-ssl-connections/

Answer (score 8):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) allows you to implement a man in the middle attack against yourself to see what is inside the SSL tunnel.

Fiddler generates a unique root SSL certificate for your computer, and then creates a session certificate signed by the root. When you configure Fiddler to decrypt SSL for you it acts as a proxy between you and the destination, decrypting the traffic using the site's SSL certificate and then re-encrypting it using its own certificate.

Your browser/application will see an untrusted certificate error. You can get around this error by choosing to trust Fiddler's root certificate.

The folks over at .Net Rocks did a great [podcast episode](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?shownum=509) on using Fiddler to sniff your traffic.

Comment: @chovy Use Charles instead of Fiddler. See https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/ for how to install the root certificate on ios.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't use it for this purpose but [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) should be able to do what you want.

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data.
>   Fiddler includes a powerful
>   event-based scripting subsystem, and
>   can be extended using any .NET
>   language.
>
> Fiddler is freeware and can debug
>   traffic from virtually any
>   application, including Internet
>   Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and
>   thousands more.

Comment: I have also used Paros proxy for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the amazingly useful Wireshark sniffer, then you can have it [decrypt SSL](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) if you are able to provide it the appropriate key files.

Comment: He likely does not have access to the server, so this won't work.